# How to merge code for DataSets?

Tags: c#, tfs, merge, dataset

Currently we are merging two branches and are having a lot of issues when it comes to the Schema/DataSets. A large part of the problem comes from the auto-generated code being moved around.

I'm curious if anyone has encountered this problem, and what solutions or tools they used to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the issue is strictly with generated code, I usually don't even try to merge the branches.

I will accept one or the other and, once the rest of the code is merged, I will re-generate the code.

Comment: What about when you alter the datasets in either branches. That's what kills us.

Comment: @Agent Worm - I assumed the datasets were being generated. What exactly is generated and what is not (and what is the code being generated from)?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. :) After re-reading and re-thinking your answer, that seem like a good approach. We decided to make a tool that would show what tables had been changed and where duplicate code from the merge had been created. It ended up being relatively simple. Although to be honest, I wasn't directly involved in this, I was mostly curious to see how others handled it. Thank you for your answer.